# Jquery UI dialog get elements the dialog is called from

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a dialog that uses jQuery UI and is opened by clicking on a link.  Is it possible to get the ID of the link that was clicked from the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code that opens the dialog, you can do this:

```
$('#the-link').click(function() {
    var dialog = ...;
    ...
    dialog.data('openingElementId', this.id);
});
```

Then, in your dialog code, you can retrieve the data that was set:

```
var openerId = this.element.data('openingElementId');
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('id') === this.id`

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi how could it be native? Browsers don't open up new dialogs on their own...

Comment: i mean native as present in jquery Ui api

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi no, jQuery only _opens_ the dialog, it doesn't know why it happened.

Answer (score 1):

If a link is opening the dialog you must have an event handler attached to the link.

Record the ID ( `this.id` ) in that handler, and pass it to the dialog, perhaps via `$.data()` or by keeping it in scope using a closure.